# Comparing two dates in Linux bash shell script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I'm trying to compare two dates. The system date vs a file date. I'm having trouble and the error I am getting is this:

> ./hello.sh: line 25: [10-18-2018: command not found

I have also tried with =,==,-eq.

```
#Setting variable
now=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
#Testing variable        
echo "Current System Date: $now"
#Setting variable        
filedate=$(date -r hello.sh "+%m-%d-%Y")
#Testing variable        
echo "hello.sh date: $filedate"

if [$now -ge  $filedate]
then
echo This statement works
else
echo This statement didnt work
fi
```

Comment: syntax errors can (usually) be debugged by pasting your code at https://shellcheck.net. You'll need to include a valid "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` will suffice. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a couple simple syntax modifications:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Setting variable
now=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
#Testing variable
echo "Current System Date: $now"
#Setting variable
filedate=$(date -r hello.sh "+%m-%d-%Y")
#Testing variable
echo "hello.sh date: $filedate"

if [[ $now ==  $filedate ]]
then
    echo "This statement works"
else
    echo "This statement didnt work"
fi
```

- in the `if`, you must put spaces after `[` and before `]`
- you are comparing text, so `-ge` does not work.  the "-" comparisons work for numbers.  Here you want to use `==` to compare text.
- Reflex for me, I put `"` around echo text.

This will work for cases where the dates are the same.  If you need "greater than" or "smaller than", put the dates in timestamp format (+%s) and compare the numbers.  Then you could use the `-ge` or others of the same type.

Comment: shellcheck.net is a great tool to verify your syntax.  Then there is this page: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide with a LOT of information.  It is a bit "dry", you could research some basic tutorials / reference on the web.